# React: Detecting if child has specific parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a smoother and cleaner way to detect if SeminarCard's parent is Slider. Currently I am passing the information via prop. The prop value (true/false) is used for some additional padding.

Standalone:

```
<SeminarCard />
```

In slider:

```
<Slider>
    <SeminarCard insideSlider/>
    <SeminarCard insideSlider/>
    <SeminarCard insideSlider/>
</Slider>
```

Comment: Personally, this feel like the smoother and cleaner way to me, can't go wrong and very obvious

Comment: Context API can also be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use React.Children, like this:

```
const Slider = (props) => {
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      {React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          insideSlider: true,
        })
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
<Slider>
  <SeminarCard />
  <SeminarCard />
  <SeminarCard />
</Slider>
```

More info how it works here for example: https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/